Use web hook for newly written reviews
I was wondering if anyone could point me into the right direction with my App (SW v 6.6.2.0):
I’d like to register to a webhook thats activated when a user writes a (new) review:
The event product_review.written does exist but according to the app:validate command it's not hookable. Which kind of is confirmed when I look at the HookableEventCollector class.
Does anyone know how to proceed here?
I also registered for similar webhooks (product:written, document:written) to see if that helps; it didnt.

As you said, the app webhook currently does not support product_review, and there is no alternative.
If you believe that should be supported just feel free to create an contribute to https://github.com/shopware/shopware
